# SQL % statement in python returns error

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, facebook-graph-api

I created 5 tables in mysql workbench 5.7 in which I will pull data from APIgraph queries for a given facebook page.

However, when I run the code, it throws an error:

> ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s, %s)' at line 1

Here is the part of the code which I think contains the error  :

```
#create connection to db
connection = connect_db()
cursor = connection.cursor()

#SQL request for inserting the date of the page into the database
insert_page = ("INSERT INTO page"
                 "(fb_id, name)"
                 "VALUES (%s, %s)")

insert_posts = ("INSERT INTO posts "
                 "(page_id, fb_post_id, message, time_created)"
                 "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)")
```

And I finally put the data at the end of the code:

```
cursor.execute(insert_page, json_pageiddata)
```

Any ideas? Thanks for helping

EDIT: here is my json_pageiddtata variable, obtained from a URL query with APIgraph:

```
    pageid_url = create_pageid_url(current_page, APP_ID, APP_SECRET)
    json_pageiddata = render_to_json(pageid_url)
    print  json_pageiddata["name"], json_pageiddata["id"]
```

Comment: can you past your ``json_pageiddata`` variable

Comment: Hi, I updated my question with your demand!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using data as dictionary u need to specify index name, try to use `%(name)s`.

Comment: Ok so i tried to replace the json_pageiddtat output by a list with the following statment: page_data = [json_pageiddata["name"], json_pageiddata["id"]]
print page_data which now return me the following error: Incorrect integer value: 'walmart' for column 'fb_id' at row 1        I precise that my value in mySQL for the page_id is BIGINT (64) and the facebook page of interest is walmart

Comment: you should respect the order of data in your query so ``fb_id, name``  - your list should be ``[json_pageiddata["id"], json_pageiddata["name"]]``

Comment: Okay, so now it does work.However, I have another issue! : **Field "idPAGE" doesn't have a default value"**. That field is my autoincrement key in my table page.   Maybe should I open another question and consider that one as resolved.

Comment: Yes, you should open a new question with SQL tag